# How to add event listener to element inside cross-domain iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

I'm trying to detect when every links get clicked and every form get submitted inside iframe. The content of the iframe is in different domain of the web page.

I've searched A LOT and all solutions failed. It works fine if the iframe from the same domain. However, when the iframe got away from the domain, the function doesn't trigger.

Is there a workaround using an external library?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/)? You will need to add the cross-domain allow policy to the other domain though. IF you have no control over the other domain's contents, I don't think you can do this since this is a security feature of the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Yes I looked at it. EasyXDM , as far as I know and correct me if I'm wrong, works for me if I have control on the content of the iframe. In my case, I don't have control on the content of the iframe and can be any website.